# Why don't CSS resets use '*' to cover all elements?

Tags: css, css-reset

For example, [the Meyer reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) has a long list of elements<sup>1</sup> which I believe can be replaced with a `*`?

I have seen some use of:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
```

But more "advanced" resets seem to go with explicitly stating the tags.

The only elements I don't see covered in the tag list that *are* covered (I presume) with a `*` are `input`, `button`, and `select`—the Eric Meyer reset, in fact, doesn't appear to really deal with those elements at all. If avoiding resetting these elements is the issue…why wouldn't you? Browsers obviously *don't* all display form elements the same.

---

<sup>**1** `html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, I, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,

figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,

menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video` if you're curious.</sup>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've guessed correctly - the reason is `form` elements.

If you set `border: 0` on for example an `input`, it will lose the native styling.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/nrB6N/

And, there's no way to get that default styling back.

Comment: (I picked `border: 0` because it's a good example and it's in the CSS reset you mentioned.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer—is there an established reset for form elements that somehow sidesteps this issue? (Perhaps using JavaScript to detect browsers and adjust padding or something accordingly by the native styling? I obviously don't really know what I'm talking about here.)

Comment: In general, you Just Don't Reset Them. Are there any particular  inconsistencies you're worried about?

Comment: Yes—I'd like to have the same 'total width' and 'total height' across all browsers, and this is obviously hard with different default border styles etc.

Comment: @luxun you could use `:not(button):not(input):not(select)` (* is implied).

Answer (score 8):

`*` is really, REALLY bad for performance (doesn't really matter on small sites, but think the repercussions for 5000+ HTML elements for example). Targetting specific elements is always faster and more efficient. It's a thing to also keep in mind when choosing wether to use an ID or an CLASS. Count in the more than common JavaScript today, and you find out that targetting elements with ID's or precise CSS statements yields in performance improvements.

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors

ps. Apart from speed, it also affects `input` elements, which after the * border, padding, and margin 0 become quite difficult to style so that they look the same accross browsers, especially in IE. Read more: http://www.christianmontoya.com/2007/02/01/css-techniques-i-use-all-the-time/

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Found, and added to my reply.

Comment: If you have 5000+ HTML elements and 4500+ of them are divs then `div` isn't going to be much better performance-wise than `*`. Selectors are generally as slow as the number of elements you have. Otherwise, `*` is just about the fastest possible selector.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly because its a performance hit. Also, since you do not want to apply reset to all elements all the time but the ones known to cause issues (around box model).

Also, resetting style of `select`, `input` may cause undesirable experience.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit here? How does it cause a performance hit (source/tests?) Why don't you want to reset all elements all the time? How does resetting of `select` and `input` cause undesirable experience[s], and what are they?

Comment: Being explicit helps you in your favorite browser - IE :). Rest of them are pretty much fine.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?