# Is this CSS Reset okay?

Tags: html, css, css-reset

I was intending to use Eric Meyer's CSS reset but I stumbled in some cross-browser differences (like `input` margins). Based on it, i came up with a more agressive aproach:

*(This is outdated. Don't forget to check the current revised version at the end of this question and criticize it as you wish)*

```
/* CSS Reset by Hugo Leonardo. Based on Eric Meyer's CSS Reset (just google it). */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;

    /* in case "font: inherit" fails (IE7) */
    font-family: "times new roman";
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    /* remove this block if you DON'T want to support lame browsers */
}

:before, :after {
    content: '';
}

:link, :visited, :hover, :active {
    color: inherit;
    color: #000; /* for IE7 'inherit' problem (again) */
    text-decoration: none;
}

:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

ol li, ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

table {
    /* "collapse" here is because of IE7 (maybe others?). don't remove it as it affects other browsers as well */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* this entire block was copied from Eric Meyer's CSS reset */
/* HTML5 "display" reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

It worked smoothly in all tested browsers:

- IE7
- IE8
- Chrome (newest)
- Firefox (newest)
- Opera (newest)

The question is: Does anyone see any trouble here? I consider myself not so good in CSS so I don't know if this will get me in any trouble in the future.

**Obs.:** this reset is for cross-browser issues only. It should (or must!) be followed by generic rules for elements like `input`, `a`, `code`, and so on (ex: `input` of type "text" would be invisible without borders!). **I will be adding things like generic `a` styles and stuff later. For now I'm resetting things, getting rid of (almost) everything that isn't the same across the major browsers.**

---

### PROBLEMS SPOTTED SO FAR

- The `*` selector could cause performance issues.
- The `*` selector with some of the rules override some default styles of elements in a way they can't be recovered. ex: the default style of an `input` of the type "submit".
- Surprisingly the `:before, :after { content: ''; }` was breaking select elements in Firefox.
- In the revised version I tried to set `margin: 0` to all input elements. Most browsers ignored it for inputs type `checkbox` and `radio`.

---

### REVISED VERSION

```
/* CSS Reset by Hugo Leonardo Leão Mota
Based on Eric Meyer's CSS Reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/
Helped by fellows in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892982/is-this-css-reset-okay */

/* resetting style for every visible element except 'ruby' family and form controls
   browsers deal with controls (and ruby style) in their own way */
a, abbr, acronym, address, b, big, blockquote, body,
br, caption, cite, code, col, colgroup, dd, del, dfn, div,
dl, dt, em, fieldset, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, html, i,
img, ins, kbd, label, legend, li, noscript, object, ol, p, pre, q, samp,
small, span, strong, sub, sup, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr, tt, ul, var {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;

    /* in case "font: inherit" fails (IE7) */
    font-family: "times new roman";
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    /* remove this block if you DON'T want to support lame browsers */
}

/* browsers are free to handle controls but
   we can't let them mess up with the other elements  */
button, select, textarea,
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=submit],
input[type=image], input[type=reset], input[type=button], input[type=file] {
    margin: 0;
}



:link, :visited, :hover, :active {
    color: inherit;
    color: #000; /* for IE7 'inherit' problem (again) */
    text-decoration: none;
}

:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

ol li, ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

table {
    /* "border-collapse" here is because of IE7 different behaviour (maybe others?).
       don't remove it as it affects other browsers as well */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* the next two blocks were copied from Eric Meyer's CSS reset */

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
}

/* HTML5 "display" reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

---

### END

Well, the more i tried to improve my reset, the more it looked like [meyer's css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/), so i gave mine up and adopted it. works just fine :p

Comment: Even though I dont agree with the `*` reset, you should reset the `line-height` of your elements.

Comment: You don't want the `*` selector for *all* elements - trust me, you're better off specifying *which* ones.

Comment: You guys were right. Got rid of `*`. Check out the revised version (:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I generally think that wide-ranging CSS resets are not the best.  I agree with Russ Weakley, who "zeroed" in on three big concerns:

1. Every element that's reset must be redefined. CSS file size & maintenance can increase.
2. You could forget to restyle something you reset.
3. Some resets are harmful to users who rely on keyboards for navigation.

See his whole presentation here: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-reset/

Specifically, I think the following should not be reset, as it is in your stylesheet

```
:before, :after {
    content: '';
}

:link, :visited, :hover, :active {
    color: inherit;
    color: #000; /* for IE7 'inherit' problem (again) */
    text-decoration: none;
}

:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

ol li, ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

`focus` is an accessibility issue.

`ol` and `ul` should have their default styles.  You are likely to need them.  (Although you may need to overwrite them for a nav.)

`:link, :visited, :hover, :active`  I would reset these only as needed.

As mentioned and acknowledged by you `*{ // }` could cause performance issues and may cause unforeseen issues.

Also, I would consider adding something to reset the big top and bottom margins on headers

`h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0;}`

Comment: Well, it's a great answer. Although a big part of it is covered by my **Obs**. That's not the end of my file, it's only for resetting differences from the browsers. **I do intend to create a lot of generic rules after that**. Why is `focus` an acessibility issue? About the heading margins, they are already covered in the first selector. I'm posting a new version right now if you want to criticize more. I really apreciate that (no kidding) (:

Comment: Thanks @hugo_leonardo!  Gotcha about more generic styles coming.  `focus` is an accessibility issue because if you tab through a form, you will have a more difficult time discerning where you are without the outline.  I added the bit about the headers because I strongly suggest you get rid of `*{ }` and the bit about headers is one thing I think you could add.

Comment: Well, i'm just trying to get rid of everything that is not the same in all browsers. Since not every browser adds the `focus` style to their inputs, i'll just do it by myself later. As you can see in the revised version, i got rid of the `*` selector (it was reeeally evil). Let me know if you spot something else wrong (:

Answer (score 4):

This is using `*` which will affect everything. You can't get borders for `input, select` etc. back in with a  "later" stylesheet.

Also, `*` is considered bad for [performance](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors). Using explicit tags is preferred.

Try [html5boilerplate's](http://html5boilerplate.com/) reset if you're having issues with Eric's (not sure if it will solve them, but worth a shot)

Comment: Why not? Why wouldn't `input {border:1px solid black;}` or `html input {border:1px solid black;}` do it?

Comment: That's not the same. I (my OS) can have different styles or even my own custom styles defined.

Comment: Since it's a generic selector it can easily be overriden. And it will be (see the 'obs'). And the whole point of a CSS reset is to remove these predefined styles! About the performance, is it a relevant difference? Because the prize sounds worth to me.

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/nrB6N/) is what this answer is referring to ([from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880002/why-dont-css-resets-use-to-cover-all-elements/6880025#6880025)). Removing the native styling for form elements in a way that can't be undone is not good. The performance aspect of `*` is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: now it makes sense...i'll review it taking that into consideration (:

Comment: @thirtydot: Thanks for pointing that out. I wanted to include that link but didn't have the time. I wish I could upvote you again on that one!

Comment: @hugo: The perforamnce difference may not be noticeable to the eye (it'll be in milliseconds _almost_ _always_) but it'll make an impact with time as your app grows (and again, IE 6/7 will be hit mostly). However, the broken styles would be a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

My only concern is the performance issue caused by using the * selector

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any trouble with it, if you've tested it and it works then it should be fine.

Comment: I think it's important to remember that a lot of issues can be solved with "if it works, then it should be fine" - that's the wrong way to look at programming. It needs to not only work, but also scale properly, and planned appropriately to avoid future issues (that you aware of yet).