# html5 reset css tips - with and without universal selector

Tags: css, html

Anyone may be using some html(5) `reset.css` for example: http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
...
```

But instead I did:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Advantages:

- Looks simpler
- weights less

Can anyone tell me if there is anything wrong with my solution (any browser thing, that I'm not aware of)?

Or what may be the advantages of listing almost all the tag names in this case?

Comment: `*` is an extremely costly selector.

Comment: FYI: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

Comment: One of the advantages of explicit listing of elements to reset is the possibility to use the default appearance of form controls. When elements like 'input' have their default 'border' and sometimes 'padding' changed, they may change their look unexpectedly, irreversibly losing some default eye-candies of the browser theme.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880002/why-dont-css-resets-use-to-cover-all-elements

Comment: CSS selector speed is not a concern. Consider: https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same question, so I searched it out and found this article:

http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Which states "If your CSS Reset isn’t carefully written, you might find that your CSS rules are being themselves overwritten by the code that was supposed to be their baseline! This is often a problem when using the Universal Selector Reset, but won’t generally be an issue if working with well-written code such as the HTML5 Doctor CSS Reset."

Hope this helps!